# Generate schema from a json object in java

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

Given a Java Class or Json Object(either one), I want generate a JSON Schema for this in java. I have been looking into the jackson library, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this(correct me if i'm wrong). Apologies if this is already posted somewhere, I found some posts on the subject but none that fit my exact needs. Thanks in advance!

Edit: i want to generate JSON schema not XSD, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate XSD files from Java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067617/generate-xsd-files-from-java-classes)

Comment: Use "jaxb" rather than "Jackson" in your search. Jaxb is the standard, Jackson just an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to generate schema from the java class then you need to Use JAXB API from the generate the schema from the java class or XML configuration. first you need to Config Maven pom.xml then Annotate your domain classes with JAXB annotations and also Annotate the XML namespace as a package annotation. you can refer below link for suitable example with code and justification:

http://www.jordeu.net/codesnips/2010/12/how-to-create-a-xsd-from-java-classes-annotated-with-jaxb/

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxbjava2schema.html